# Are there better alternatives to :Any for a swiftui struct value?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to implement an app where the response from a server call is used to build a view. The view can be one of 5 or 6 different types, depending on the data that comes back, all of which have different requirements for the shape and type of the data that gets passed in to them. Whats the best way to define the struct/class for the incoming data? The only way I've been able to make it work so far is by using :Any as the data type

This is the broad strokes of what I'm trying to do...

```
struct PageViewData {
    type: String
    id: Int
    viewData: Any
}

struct MyViewA: View {
    type: String
    id: Int
    viewData: MyViewADataShape

    var body: some View {
        //contents here
    }
}

struct MyViewADataShape {
    navigation: [NavigationItem] 
    cta: String
}

struct MyViewB: View {
    type: String
    id: Int
    viewData: MyViewBDataShape

    var body: some View {
        //contents here
    }
}

struct MyViewBDataShape {
    pageTitle: String
    author: String
    wordCount: Int
}

var serverResponse: PageViewData = fetchDataFromServer()

if(serverResponse.type == "A") {
    MyViewA(serverResponse)
}

if(serverResponse.type == "B") {
    MyViewB(serverResponse)
}
```

Comment: I've yet to work out how, but I was wondering if enum could be used to allow multiple structs to pass type checking on a single variable?

Comment: Yes, you can use an enum with associated values. See [Enumerations in the Swift book](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID148)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Yonat mentioned, an `enum` works well here:

```swift
struct PageView: View {
    enum Response {
        case something(DecodableResponseA)
        case orOther(DecodableResponseB)
    }

    // if you were using id + type to determine what your response was, they are
    // unnecessary now, but only you know what you were using them for
    let id: Int
    let response: Response

    var body: some View {
        self.viewForResponse(response)
    }

    private func viewForResponse(_ response: Response) -> some View {
         switch response {
         case .something(let somethingResponse): return AnyView(SomethingView())
         case .orOther(let orOtherResponse): return AnyView(OtherView())
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain with a coded example how this would work - so much easier for me to follow that the Apple/3rd party documentation. Much appreciated!